# How to commence and stop highlighting text using VBA's HighlightColorIndex

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am pulling text from another application and creating a MS-Word document on the fly.

Occasionally there may be some highlighting of words needed which I perform as I find these. What I cannot understand is how to cease displaying the HighlightColorIndex.

I've tried Selection.Collapse, Selection.Range.Collapse and Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight all to limited success. Can you assist please?

```
Dim lngRangeStart As Long
Dim lngRangeEnd As Long
Selection.TypeText Text:="Test of colour" ' No highlighting at present
Selection.TypeParagraph                   ' 
Selection.TypeText Text:="Starting colour after colon: " ' No highlighting at present

lngRangeStart = Selection.Start   ' set to the start of the Range

Selection.Range.StartOf
Selection.TypeText Text:="This text is highlighted"

lngRangeEnd = Selection.Start ' set to the end of the Range and sel.start appears correct

Selection.SetRange Start:=lngRangeStart, End:=lngRangeEnd ' sets range correctly
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

' >>> This is where I need to cease highlighting but what to do?
{funky code to stop highlighting here}
Selection.TypeText Text:="Now back to clear text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select text as you did before and reset its highlight to none `wdNoHighlight`

Use below code

```
' >>> This is where I need to cease highlighting but what to do?
'{funky code to stop highlighting here}
Selection.Move WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1
''Clear for text
lngRangeStart = Selection.Start
Selection.TypeText text:="Now back to clear text"
lngRangeEnd = Selection.Start
Selection.SetRange Start:=lngRangeStart, End:=lngRangeEnd ' sets range correctly
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

Selection.Move WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1
Selection.TypeText text:="Now back to the future text"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you just set the highlight color to `wdColorAutomatic`, which is a constant specifying the automatic (default) color.

So putting it all together, to highlight text, you'd set its background to `wdColorYellow`. To remove the highlighting, you'd set its background to `wdColorAutomatic`.